# How to show jqgrid columns editable on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am working on JQgrid in which 2 columns need to be editable, I've achieved it using below options in `colModel`.

```
{
  name: 'Action',
  index: 'Action',
  editable: true,
  edittype: "select",
  formatter: 'select',
  editoptions: {
    value: {
      1: 'Approve',
      2: 'Reject'
    }
  },
  editrules: {
    required: true,
    custom: true,
    custom_func: actionCheck
  }
},
```

and below two options in `jqgrid`

```
cellEdit: true,
cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
```

But with this, I have to click on the column to be able to edit it.

I also have a column named `comments` with `edittype:"textarea"`.

What I want is, when users open the page they see dropdowns and textareas in both columns of all rows and when they click the submit button after entering the data, I grab all of it in an array, which I will then use to update my SharePoint list.

Is this possible? if so please let me know how.

here's what I currently have,

[image: here is what I currently have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With celEdit you can't do what you want. You can use both methods editRow and saveRow. Please, check the docs for this purpose.

The idea is to call editRow after the data is loaded. This can be done with setTimeout function after the jqGrid code. Make these two fields editable and do.

```
...
jqGrid({
...
});

setTimeout(function() {
    var grid = $("#jqGrid");
    var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        grid.jqGrid('editRow',ids[i]);
    }
}, 800);
```

After that you can save the data on button click. The button should be defined somewhere in the DOM.

```
    function saveRows() {
        var grid = $("#jqGrid");
        var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            grid.jqGrid('saveRow', ids[i]);
        }
    }
```

Please check the similar [example here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/inline_batch/index.html)